# How to display millions of seconds in human readable form (years, months, days, hours, minutes)

Tags: python, time

I have sums that are millions of seconds. I want to display that amounts in human-readable form. Like if I have 5 000 000 seconds, that accounts for `X years, Y months, Z days, V hours W minutes`?

I can calculate it manually, but I'm hoping for a prettier, built in pythonic datetime library method I am unable to find.

Comment: How many days in a year?  365?  365.25?  How many days in a month?  etc, etc.  This isn't a well posed problem ...

Comment: Aside from anything else, you'll need to specify a base point. 30 days from the end of January has a different number of months in it than 30 days from the end of November.

Comment: Thanks, mgilson, for your comment but I'm looking for a prettier solution. I will eventually fallback to manual calculation.

Comment: Veseliq, @mgilson's comment applies no matter whether how you calculate the results. The length of a year and especially the length of a month are not constant, so it's impossible to use them for accurate arbitrary lengths of time. You either have to accept that the answer will be approximate, or tie one end to a particular date.

Comment: Even if you ignore minor details like leap seconds, months can be either 28, 29, 30, or 31 days. So it's impossible to know how many months unless you know the specific dates involved.

Comment: That is correct. I flagged it for closing (as I can not delete it with anser). There is no way to have a built in solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well at least if you're just talking millions of seconds, datetime.timedelta at least gets you partway there:

```
import datetime
print datetime.timedelta(seconds=5000000)

57 days, 20:53:20
```

But as others have noted, how big do you want a month to be?  Without a time frame, to start/end the count, any sort of breakdown beyond days or weeks is meaningless.